# Subsetting list elements using contents of list elements

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply

I have a nested list called `nested_list`.

```
nested_list <- list(B.Al = list(ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData = structure(c(0.739, 
651, 91.589, 82.353), .Dim = c(1L, 4L), .Dimnames = list("KAPPA", 
    c("Testing.data", "Cutoff", "Sensitivity", "Specificity")))), OA.Al = list(ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData = structure(c(0.632, 
654, 77.57, 92.157), .Dim = c(1L, 4L), .Dimnames = list("KAPPA", 
    c("Testing.data", "Cutoff", "Sensitivity", "Specificity")))), B.Ca = list(ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData = structure(c(0.47, 
556, 90.654, 50.98), .Dim = c(1L, 4L), .Dimnames = list("KAPPA", 
    c("Testing.data", "Cutoff", "Sensitivity", "Specificity")))))
```

The elements of `nested_list` are `B.Al`, `OA.Al`, and `B.Ca`.  `nested_list$B.Al`, `nested_list$OA.Al`, and `nested_list$B.Ca` are also lists.

`class(nested_list)` returns `"list"`
`class(nested_list$B.Al)` returns `"list"`

The only element in the lists `nested_list$B.Al`, `nested_list$OA.Al`, and `nested_list$B.Ca` is a matrix (ie, `nested_list$B.Al$ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData`). This matrix has a column labelled 'Testing.data'.

I want to determine which of `nested_list$B.Al$ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData`, `nested_list$OA.Al$ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData`, and `nested_list$B.Ca$ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData` has the highest 'Testing.data' value, and I want to return a list with only the one that is highest.

In this example, `nested_list$B.Al$ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData[1]` = 0.739. 
`nested_list$OA.Al$ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData[1]` = 0.632. 
`nested_list$B.Ca$ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData[1]` = 0.47. 
So, `B.Al` has the highest value for 'Testing.data'. Therefore, I want to return the following list;

```
result <- list(B.Al = list(ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData = structure(c(0.739, 
651, 91.589, 82.353), .Dim = c(1L, 4L), .Dimnames = list("KAPPA", 
    c("Testing.data", "Cutoff", "Sensitivity", "Specificity")))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the value of `'Testing.data'` from each list, use `which.max` to get the index of maximum value and use it to subset `nested_list`.

```
nested_list[which.max(sapply(nested_list, function(x) x[[1]][, 'Testing.data']))]

#$B.Al
#$B.Al$ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData
#      Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
#KAPPA        0.739    651      91.589      82.353
```